# Creating a super matrix using openCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, matrix, reshape

I have to create a 4800 x 5 super matrix. This matrix will consist of 5 images of size 80 x 60 which I have already reshaped into matrices of 4800 x 1 using cvReshape. Therefore, I would now like to place these images next to the other to get a super matrix of dimensions 4800 x 5. How can I go about doing this using openCV? I have been trying all a long while now and this is due soon but I am no closer to achieving the creation of this matrix. I would really appreciate if someone could please help me. This is my code so far. However, it is not working, much less for giving the output I want.

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 
#include "iostream" 

using namespace std; 

void cvDoubleMatPrint (const CvMat* mat)
{
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < mat->rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0 ; j < mat->cols; j++)
    {
        printf ( "%f ", cvGet2D (mat, i , j));
    }
    printf ( "\n" );
}
}


int main( int argc, char* argv ) 
{ 
CvMat *img0, *img1,  *img0_mat, *img1_mat, *col0, *col1, *superMat, *col0_mat, *col1_mat, *superMat_mat = NULL;

img0 = cvLoadImageM("C:\\small\\walk mii.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);    
img1 = cvLoadImageM("C:\\small\\wave mii.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);    
img0_mat = img0;
img1_mat = img1;//what does this do!!!

CvMat col0_header, col1_header, superMat_header, img0_header, img1_header;

col0 = cvReshape(img0_mat, &img0_header, 0, 4800);
col1 = cvReshape(img1_mat, &img1_header, 0, 4800);
col0_mat = col0;
col1_mat = col1;

superMat = cvCreateMat(4800, 2, CV_8UC1);
superMat_mat = superMat;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cvGetCol(col0_mat, &col0_header, 1);
    cvGetCol(superMat_mat, &superMat_header, 1);
    cvCopy(col0_mat, superMat_mat);
}

cvDoubleMatPrint(superMat_mat);

cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the code I have currently, I just am trying to stack 2 images next to each other. Once I am able to do this, I would then go about adding on the 3 more images. Therefore, as for now, I am trying to create a 4800 x 2 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy each image matrix row by row as illustrated in the code below:

```
cv::Mat superMat;
cv::Mat rowImg1, rowImg2, ..

superMat.create(5,rowImg.cols,rowImg1.type());

for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
  rowImg1.copyTo(superMat.row(i));  
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying Eric. I had to modify your code to use it since I am using an older version of openCV with C++. However, I am now getting an error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments. Would you please look through my code (edited above in the question) and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: In C-style opencv, `CvMat->rows()` don't take argument and give you the number of rows of your matrix. To get row-matrix, you need to use `CvGetRow` function

Comment: I did as you advised. Please see the edited version above. Howver, now I am getting an: 'Unhandled exception at 0x768cb9bc in scatchpad.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x003af338'. Any advice for fix this? Also, please clarify something for me. In the loop, how would nthe code know after it has copied the 1st image into column 1 of the super matrix, that it should now copy the 2nd image into column 2 of the super matrix? I think the loop is inaccurately expressed in my code for this to happen.

Comment: I was able to get the supermatrix. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a new matrix of the same data type of size 4800x5 with cvCreateMat and load the 5 images into this "super matrix" row-by-row.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I tried your advice but I am getting an error. In any case, I do not think I am doing exactly what you meant for me to try. I would greatly appreciate it if you would take a look at my code, which I edited above in the original question, and advise me as to how to fix it please.