# how to convert multidimensional c++ array into openCV form?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copy data from one matrix to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617308/copy-data-from-one-matrix-to-another)

I have an array in c++ like this:

```
double myValue[600][800][3];
```

and I want to convert it into openCV multidimensional matrix or scalar form. I tried doing something like this:

```
double size[] = {600, 800};
cv::Mat myValue (size, 3, CV_8UC3 );
```

But it is wrong, could someone help me?

Comment: *"I tried `cv::Mat myMat (size, 3, CV_8U3C )`. But it is wrong"* - Huh? Maybe because this line doesn't even include **any** reference to `myValue`? How should it magically be related to `myValue` in any way? Please don't say it just refuses to compile because you used `CV_8U3C` instead of `CV_8UC3`.

Comment: sorry, my typo, it is myValue, not myMat, and CV_8UC3. I editted it.

Comment: Huh? Now the names of both objects interfere and the declaration of the `cv::Mat` still doesn't reference the `double` array in any way, how should it take its values?

Comment: In StackOverflow it's not allowed to post the same question twice!

Comment: @Christian: please forget its values, I can declare it as zero matrix if wanted. What I want to ask is how to declare multidimensional opencv mat.

Comment: @vasile: yes I know, but I can't see these two questions are similar. what did I miss here?

Comment: ok, I think I found something useful here in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668951/creating-a-super-matrix-using-opencv

Comment: @vasile: I got what you mean. could you please help me delete this question now? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, you have to do basic research by looking at manual or searching web before asking a question. If you don't do that, it is very difficult for us to give you an understandable answer.

Accessing elements of cv::Mat or matrix conversion is really basic stuff in OpenCV. Please refer to [cheatsheet if you are that busy.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf)

To answer your question, I don't think there is a short cut to convert multidimensional array to Mat. You should loop through elements to copy the data into Mat. That's why many people use single dimensional array to speed things up for faster image processing.

Comment: yes, I've already searched a lot before asking this question. And from the web I found there are some functions in opencv like "cvSplit" or "cvMixChannels", etc. So I thought there could be other functions/faster way to do such conversion between multidimensional array to cvMat, and asked this question here. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.